# Freeze ticket or cancel - United Airlines

Tags: usa, covid-19, united-airlines

I bought 3 tickets to travel to the united states for my wife and little daughter for late November 2022.

My wife doesn't have an American citizenship and has a valid visa, but we didn't think about the fact she doesn't want to get covid-19 shots.

I can or cancel the 3 tickets for 100$ or freeze the tickets until the end of 2023, by then I'm sure no proof of fully vaccinated will be needed.

but the clerk said that when I buy the new tickets if the tickets will cost more, "additional fee will be charged".

Are United Airlines reliable on the freeze tickets, or they'll probably rip me off later and I should just cancel?

Thank you for the advice.

Comment: If you have no concrete plans, then I would personally cancel the tickets and eat the $100 loss. While I can make no predictions, it's quite likely that the vaccine mandates will be lifted before 2023. USA's neighbour Canada lifted all mandates this month, it's only a matter of time before America follows up.

Comment: @nikhil thank you. I have concrete plans, another thing, cancelation with the low fee is just until the end of this week. freezing the ticket is until the plane takes off. The same ticket I bought, is now, a week later 30% up.

Comment: @Midavalo I am a US citizen. I haven't seen such an exemption.

Comment: @AJAJ You may be right - I also can't find it, I must be thinking of a different exemption.  I'll delete my comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are United Airlines reliable on the freeze tickets, or they'll probably rip me off later and I should just cancel?

They will most definitely charge a difference between the fare you paid and the current fare of the ticket you're rebooking, when you rebook it. There's no "freezing" tickets, there's canceling. You can cancel for refund (with $100 fee, as you were told), or cancel for credit (applicable for a new ticket) without any fee. The credit would be for the amount paid for the original ticket, but if the new ticket is more expensive - you'll need to add funds. If the new ticket is cheaper - the remainder will stay as credit (until it expires).

Comment: Whether or not there is a change fee will depend on the rules of the specific ticket that has been purchased.  Without additional information it's not possible to say whether there would a change fee or not.

Comment: @Doc I think the OP described the info they got from United quite clearly.

Comment: So?  The vast majority of United tickets purchased outside of the US have change fees.  It depends on the exact fare rules as to what the fees would be.

Comment: @doc you're correct! Israel has a 14 days law, the purchase can be canceled for 5% of the cost or 100 NIS (app. 30$), the lower between them.